# vsftpd drops connection on PASV command with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04, ftp

This is what I see:

```
$ telnet ec2-???-???-232-82.compute-1.amazonaws.com 21
Trying ???.???.232.82...
Connected to ec2-???-???-232-82.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
USER foo
331 Please specify the password.
PASS secret
230 Login successful.
PASV
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Why this may happen?

This is part of `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=5000
pasv_max_port=5200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to authorise the chosen passive ports for your instance. This can be done in the AWS management console with

`ec2-authorize default -p <starting port>-<end port>`

so it should be

`ec2-authorize default -p 5000-5200`

in your case.

Edit: and of course, don't forget to note the public adress with

`pasv_address=???.???.232.82`

like you pointed out.

Comment: I was leaving out the pasv_address.  After adding that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For others ending up here 7 years later: I had a problem with immediately dropped connections on an EC2 instance after `PASV`, caused by vsftpd listening on ipv6.

Fixed by setting `listen_ipv6=NO` and `listen=YES`.